# Do while loop with jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, do-while

I'm trying to generate a random number and if the value gotten from the jtable is a hyphen I want it to random again. I'm doing a do while loop however none of these while loops are working. I dont know what i'm missing?
EDIT: Whoops I found out my fault, my action listener was running the wrong method that I created, thanks for help

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: Incidentally, your parentheses are in the wrong places, on the line that sets `randomNum` - but the only effect of that is that you'll never select the last row of your table, unless there's only one row.

Comment: what output or exception you are getting ?

Comment: Theres no exception being printed, it does what it says. It prints out the values that the random number being generated even if its a hyphen. What i'm trying to do it not print the hypens and rerandomize the number if it is

Comment: You should provided a runnable example that demonstrates your problem, this will remove any guess work

Comment: Are there spaces or some other invisible characters around the hyphens?

Comment: Nope, I am using a soft hyphen rather than a normal hyphen if it makes a difference?

Comment: Well, yes, it makes a difference.  If you've got a soft hyphen in your JTable, and you're using `equals` to compare it with a normal hyphen, then **of course** it's going to return false.

Comment: Nononono, I have soft hyphens in both.

Comment: You shouldn't remove your question just because you found an answer.  The whole point of Stack Overflow is that one person's question is likely to be useful to another person.  So we build up a database of useful questions and answers.  Would you consider restoring your question, and maybe posting an answer that indicates what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your parenthesis proper like below and run

```
randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * (stuTable.getRowCount() - 1));
```

check it out

Comment: That will make no difference at all - and they're still actually in the wrong places.

Comment: can you tel how above my lines are having still wrong parenthesis please ?

Comment: It doesn't matter it still does the same thing

Comment: There is no difference between (stuTable.getRowCount() - 1)) and ((stuTable.getRowCount()) - 1)), it will produce the same result

Comment: As I pointed out, this does exactly the same thing as before, so this is not what is causing OP the problem.  But with the parentheses where you have them, if there are 10 rows (for example), you're going to get a result between 0 and 8 - that is, you'll never select the last row.